# TabLayout - не переключается по нажатию

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, tab, android-tablayout

Прикрутил TabLayout из 4 фрагментов, он листается, но на нажатие на заголовок не реагирует, как исправить?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;

DB db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    db = new DB(this);
    initUI();

}

private void initUI() {

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viepager);

    viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout.Tab fragMain = tabLayout.newTab();
    TabLayout.Tab fragIncome = tabLayout.newTab();
    TabLayout.Tab fragCategory = tabLayout.newTab();
    TabLayout.Tab fragReport = tabLayout.newTab();

    fragMain.setText("Расходы");
    fragIncome.setText("Доходы");
    fragCategory.setText("Категории");
    fragReport.setText("Отчет");

    tabLayout.addTab(fragMain, 0);
    tabLayout.addTab(fragIncome, 1);
    tabLayout.addTab(fragCategory, 2);
    tabLayout.addTab(fragReport, 3);

    tabLayout.setTabTextColors(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this, R.color.tab_selector));
    tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorTotalSumm));

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

}
```

Адаптер

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

private final Fragment frag [] = new Fragment[4];


public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    frag [0] = new ContentMainFragment();
    frag [1] = new AddingIncomeFragment();
    frag [2] = new AddingCategoryFragment();
    frag [3] = new AddingTaskFragment4();
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return frag[position];
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return frag.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не переключалось т.к. TabLayout был не внутри ViewPager'a (в разметке)

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, вам поможет добавление подключения табов к пэйджеру [так](https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout):

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Comment: Не помогло, только исчезли названия из Titlle

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй `onClick` для каждого фрагмента. Плюс можешь попробывать таким способом:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == ваш загаловок фрагмента) {

    }
```

Comment: Причем тут onClick, я говорю про TabLayout?!